# Google app engine cron job not working, http timeout?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

**Problem running cron job. Cron job always shows failed on the google developer console, and there seems to be no way to find out why. If I use the web site appspot.com/crons/ftpcronjon it executes just fine.**

Here is my code:

```
import httplib2
import logging
import webapp2
from apiclient import discovery
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials( scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute' )
HTTP = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))

compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', http=HTTP)

PROJECT_ID = "project-id"

INSTANCE = "json/rest body of instance parameters, this works"

class vmlaunchftp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request=None, response=None):
        self.initialize(request, response)

    def get(self):
        request = compute.instances().insert(project=PROJECT_ID, body=INSTANCE, zone="us-central1-b" )
        response = request.execute(http=HTTP)


APPLICATION = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/crons/ftpcronjob', vmlaunchftp)], debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: sh-vo-001
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
#cron job
- url: /crons/ftpcronjob
  script: vmlaunch.APPLICATION

#Endpoint handler
- url: .*
  script: main.APPLICATION

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: vmlaunch.py 
  url: /crons/ftpcronjob
  schedule: every day 11:30
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles
```

I suspect it fails because the response from request.execute times out, but why does it work from the web site?

How do you launch jobs on VMs from appengine, without using task queues?

really how do we debug issues like this without adequate real time updating log files?

EDIT: Added app.yaml, cron.yaml ; works on devserver, but the credentials are bad as expected!

Comment: can you show your cron.yaml? Does it work if you execute it on the localhost? why do you need the __init__ btw?

Comment: thanks marcadian, My other crons work, so not a total newbie. app.yaml and cron.yaml added above. The init was in most examples so I copied :)

Comment: You can debug this problem by using target parameter for your cron so that it's running on a specific version, therefore it's easier to find corresponding logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are just no logs anywhere for this cron job. Just fails, confounding frustrating. My only option is to write another cron to do a wget on the cron web link to trigger it, which my programming instinct says not too :).

Comment: as @marcadian says, using a dedicated version to debug what's going on might help. Also, add some logging to your handler, so you can pin-point until where execution goes. Finally, checkout the new logs viewer, which is a bit better, and you might be able to find what you need easily